# Clustering Algorithms- Sample Size

Tags: clustering, categorical-data, sample-size

I have a small sample (290 observations) of categorical data and I am trying to decide on what clustering method to use. I am considering k-medoids, hierarchical clustering and Latent Class Clustering. I am not sure yet how many variables I will include in the clustering, but I assume around 7-10. I understand that there is not a definite answer on what is the most appropriate and different researchers use different techniques. But I was wondering if anyone was aware of any papers/ books mentioning anything about sample size that maybe could help my decision?
e.g. on LCC I found: https://ro.uow.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=1286&context=commpapers p.2

Many thanks in advance and apologies if my question is not very clear I am very new to this :)

Comment: Sample size? Just use all 290?

Comment: I will, but I was wondering which method would be more appropriate considering the small number of observations